# Placeholder page while live Magento site is being worked on

Tags: php, .htaccess, magento, hosting, magento-1.7

I'm converting a site from an ASP shopping cart to Magento. I had to switch hosts to a php server. A lot of the configurations I'm testing require that I have the site hosted on the domain (SSL, module keys, etc).

I set up the new host, have everything set up database and magento wise. But I wanted to know if there was a way to have a landing page on the root while working on magento site on the live url. so if you go to example.com it takes you to the landing page (index.html) but I can bypass this by going to example.com/index.php.

I could put this on a subdomain but that is not ideal since I don't have an SSL cert on subdomains and some of the modules won't be activated on there as well.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as it is up right now and don't want users to see the beta site.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just make a file int the root folder and call it "maintenance.flag" magento is redirecting to the "Underconstruction"-File automatically. You might want to style that file though since the default is rather ugly

Comment: Great solution - I found this article that is a combination of Syfaro's answer and yours: http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/maintenance-mode-in-magento/

Answer (score 1):

I used this .htaccess file so that only I could access the page.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^xxx\.xxx\.xxx\.xxx
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/index.html$ [NC]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpe?g?|png|gif) [NC]
 RewriteRule .* /index.html [R=302,L]
</IfModule>
```

(replace the "x"s with your IP address)

This redirects everything to index.html, unless it's from your IP address.

Comment: That seems like a great solution although multiple people need to check it to sign off on the site before I take down the landing page.

Comment: You can modify the RegEx fairly easily, you can just change the single thing to accept multiple different values. To do so change `!^xxx\.xxx\.xxx\.xxx` to `!^(xxx\.xxx\.xxx\.xxx|xxx\.xxx\.xxx\.xxx)`, and so forth (just adding a `|` and the IPs with a backslash before each `.` in the parenthesis).

Answer (score 0):

If you go for the sub-directory version, just work with `.htaccess` to authenticate access:

http://www.htaccesstools.com/htpasswd-generator/

Otherwise, in the root folder, you may do the following

`.htaccess`:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html

AuthType Basic
AuthName "My Protected Area"
AuthUserFile .htpasswd
Require valid-user

<FilesMatch "index.html">
  Allow from all
  Satisfy any
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: Thanks w0rldart although I don't require authentication. I tried setting the DirectoryIndex to index.html and when I go to any other page of the site I'm getting a loopback error.

Comment: the `DirectoryIndex ...` thing is only for the root folder. And this is more precise, if your clients/you have dynamic ips because you'll have to always update them. This works

Comment: Dynamic IP's won't be an issue since this is only up for a few hours for testing

Comment: While this works, it will foul up the image uploader. Been there, done that. Use the .htaccess to just limit the incoming IP addresses allowed access on the site.